# Align Images To The Right Within a Table Data (td) Cell

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

I have a `<td>` img element within my `react-bootstrap` table that I want to align to the right. Currently, it's set to have a `marginLeft` of 10px after the text to the left (see picture) but I would like all the `img`s to be consistent in a single "column" within the `td`, if that makes sense. In this case, all the crests would more or less be level with Brighton and Hove Albion, as they are the longest string.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
                  <td>
                    <span>{convertTeamIdToName(data.teamId)}</span>
                    <span style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}>
                      <img
                        src={retrieveTeamCrest(data.teamId)}
                        height="32"
                        width="32"
                        alt={data.teamName}
                      />
                    </span>
                  </td>
```

How would I go about changing this in css/inline styling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is number of ways to do this. You can use flexbox features or reserve place for images with padding of `td` element and position them absolutely. Here is one option, with float (just don't forget to put image tag before the text):

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
}

td {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.team-logo {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="team-logo"><img src="http://placehold.it/32.jpg"></span>
            <span class="team-title">Lorem</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="team-logo"><img src="http://placehold.it/32.jpg"></span>
            <span class="team-title">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="team-logo"><img src="http://placehold.it/32.jpg"></span>
            <span class="team-title">Lorem</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Though I'd put logos before the name of the team ;-)
[image: logos positioning comparison]